# Diablo 3 - Weapon damage based abilities

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is skill damage calculated based on weapon damage?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60281/how-is-skill-damage-calculated-based-on-weapon-damage)

I am confused a little bit about weapon-damage based abilities. My minimum weapon damage for my barbarian is 1066. If I use Weapon Throw (which damages "for 100% weapon damage"), I will hit for around 15,000 damage. Based on this little bit of information, and the tool-tip supplied by Diablo, the damage is actually my weapon damage (1066) multiplied by your strength divided by 100, multiplied by the spell percentage (100).

This all makes sense, until I analyze another spell (Earthquake):

Let S equal 12.51 (my strength/100).
Let P equal 2000 (percentage based on Earthquake)
Let D equal 1066 (my lowest weapon damage)

S*P*D = 26.67132 million.

Based on this, earthquake should be doing ~3.3 million damage per second. Comparing my standard output (around 40k DPS (according to Blizzard)), to the damage of Earthquake, it just doesn't seem true at all. What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is skill damage calculated based on weapon damage?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60281/how-is-skill-damage-calculated-based-on-weapon-damage). See also [How do the damage calculations work in Diablo 3?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42481/how-do-the-damage-calculations-work-in-diablo-3) and [What does the Damage stat on the character sheet actually mean?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67843/what-does-the-damage-stat-on-the-character-sheet-actually-mean-how-is-it-calcul/67844#67844)

Comment: From what I can tell of these links, which I read prior to posting, they do not explain the difference in damage. The how is skill-damage calculated, is contrary to this and the other two links seem to have nothing to do with this question. If you disagree please point me to what I am missing in those posts.

Comment: Your math doesn't make sense.  15,000 is definitely not 1066 *12.51 * 100.  2000% is 20 times more than 100%, so Earthquake should be doing 20 times more than your Weapon Throw, or only about 300,000.

Comment: Ah, you are right. That makes perfect sense.